# Could not install packages due to an OSError

Tags: pytorch, google-colaboratory, requirements.txt

https://youtu.be/tFNJGim3FXw?si=xGuTPc_7xBFrtID7

i tried to build this program but when i try the third code it's already have an error saying
Collecting en-core-web-sm@ https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-3.6.0/en_core_web_sm-3.6.0-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=83276fc78a70045627144786b52e1f2728ad5e29e5e43916ec37ea9c26a11212 (from -r requirements.txt (line 83))
Downloading https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-3.6.0/en_core_web_sm-3.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (12.8 MB)
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 12.8/12.8 MB 76.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Processing /colabtools/dist/google-colab-1.0.0.tar.gz (from -r requirements.txt (line 139))
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/colabtools/dist/google-colab-1.0.0.tar.gz'

!cd yolov5 & pip install -r requirements.txt --user
I read through the answers given and tried out this !cd yolov5 & pip install -r requirements.txt --user. Despite this working for many others, it still did not work for me.

i also try few  things to fix it, but it won't do anything

just like in the video it's should show no output when it properly run